# MySql: Concat IF'ed values

Tags: mysql

Trying to find a way to combine CONCAT with IF – or in some other way display
textual value for set flags in a comma separated list.

*Note: This is eventually for a table with 10+ columns. Using two here to simplify.*

Say I have a table with flags. If flag is `1` I want to display some textual value,
else nothing.

```
origin:
+--+-----+-----+
|# | CHS | ACC |
+--+-----+-----+
|1 | 0   | 1   |
|2 | 1   | 1   |
|3 | 1   | 0   |
|4 | 0   | 0   |
+--+-----+-----+
```

I want:

```
+--+----------+
|# |  origin  |
+--+----------+
|1 | ACC      |
|2 | CHS, ACC |
|3 | CHS      |
|4 |          |
+--+----------+
```

Not (this or the like):

```
+--+-----------+
|# | origin    |
+--+-----------+
|1 | ACC,      |
|2 | CHS, ACC, |
|3 | CHS,      |
|4 | ,         |
+--+-----------+
```

Something in the direction of this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
        IF(CHS = 0, '', 'CHS'),
        IF(ACC = 0, '', 'ACC')
    ) as origin
FROM
    origin;
```

But not with comma between empty values.

This is eventually for a table with 10 columns that I join with other table based
on id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use CONCAT_WS, that skips NULL values, in combination with CASE:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CONCAT_WS(', ',
    CASE WHEN CHS THEN 'CHS' END,
    CASE WHEN ACC THEN 'ACC' END
  ) as origin
FROM
  origin;
```

When the condition is FALSE, since I am not specifying an ELSE clause, CASE will return a NULL value, and CONCAT_WS will skip it. You could also use NULL on your original query instead of ''.

If you have many columns, you can also create a dynamic query with something like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT ID, CONCAT_WS(\', \',',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        'CASE WHEN ',
        `COLUMN_NAME`,
        ' THEN \'',
        `COLUMN_NAME`,
        '\' END') SEPARATOR ','),
    ') AS origin FROM origin;'
    )
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE
  `TABLE_NAME`='origin'
  AND COLUMN_NAME!='id'
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please see fiddle, with both solutions, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b53b8/1).

Comment: Great. This works nice. The use of `COLUMN_NAME` makes it even better.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a nicer looking solution, but you can use

```
CONCAT(
    IF(CHS = 0, '', 'CHS'),
    IF(CHS != 0 AND ACC != 0, ', ', ''),
    IF(ACC = 0, '', 'ACC')
)
```

You could also use `REPLACE` to remove the "blanks:"

```
REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(', ',
    IF(CHS = 0, 'REMOVEIT', 'CHS'),
    IF(ACC = 0, 'REMOVEIT', 'ACC')
), 'REMOVEIT, ', '')
```

Comment: Yes. Considered that, only with 10 columns it started to look very ugly ;)

Comment: Thanks. I need to have multiple REPLACE statements though, (or find another clever way to remove all REMOVEIT's), I'm looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM CONCAT_WS(', ',
        IF(CHS = 0, '', 'CHS'),
        IF(ACC = 0, '', 'ACC')
    )) as origin
FROM
    origin;
```

Here is the mysql documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: Thank you. Though this does not work too good with 3+ columns it is valuable information.

Comment: If the schema is in your control, I would suggest you to put the column names as values in a separate table, and use the foreign key reference in the origin table to simplify things.  This will also allow you to add more values on the fly by just inserting rows instead of adding more columns to the origin table.